# Combining and aligning "chart" type graphics with regular plots

Tags: plotting

Is there an easy (recommended) way to align regular plots (e.g. `ListPlot` or `Plot`) with chart type graphics (`BarChart` or `DistributionChart`)?

For example:

```
Show[
   DistributionChart[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[i, .2], 1000], {i, 1, 10}]], 
   ListPlot[Range[1, 10]]
]
```

[image: Not aligned!]

I would like the points of the `ListPlot` to reside exactly on top of the `DistributionChart` elements. Furthermore, the coordinate positioning of chart elements seems to vary with the number of elements (which is ridiculous).

```
Show[
    DistributionChart[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[i, .2], 1000], {i, 1, 3}]], 
    ListPlot[Range[1, 3]]
]
```

[image: Not aligned 2]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing something different? [This is what I get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lZSo4.png) (and a similar correct figure for the second case). Try doing it in a fresh kernel (and without custom options, if any)

Comment: @R.M I get the same as the OP. Version mismatch?

Comment: I get the same output as @R.M (v 8.0.4.0 Windows Vista 64 bit)

Comment: No, fresh kernel doesn't help. I plotted the diagrams with Mathematica 8.0.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.7. Tried it on Windows with the same Mathematica version and get the same result. Which version are you using @R.M ?

Comment: I get the same as R.M with Mathematica 8.0.4 for OS X.

Comment: I'm using 8.04 too... so looks like it's yet another inconsistency between 8.00 and 8.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems it is a problem localized to version 8.0.0. Here is a way to fix it by scaling your `ListPlot` using the `FrameTicks` of the `DistributionChart`.

```
k = DistributionChart[Table[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[i, .2], 100], {i, 1, 20}], 
         Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> "Fixed"}]; 
l = (Sort@((FrameTicks /. Options[k, "FrameTicks"])[[2, 1, All, 1]]))[[2 ;; -2]];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range@Length@l, l}]];
Show[k, ListPlot[Table[{f@i, i}, {i, 15}], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]