# Combine DistributionChart and ListPlot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining and aligning “chart” type graphics with regular plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/combining-and-aligning-chart-type-graphics-with-regular-plots)

I have a bunch of data I want to plot a violin plot of, and I want to add the averages (as points) as well as some other curves (in one graphic). However, combining `DistributionChart` with `Plot` commands such as `ListPlot` does not seem to be straightforward. For example, I have no trouble creating the violin plot

[image: violin plot]

and the point plot

[image: point plot]

but combining both using `Show` results in this:

[image: broken combination]

Apparently, Mathematica treats distribution charts as scale-free entities but uses its knowledge of numerical scale for plots, and can't mix both. Is there a way around this?

---

For convenience, I declare some functions first:

```
load[file_] := Import[file, "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 1,
                            "FieldSeparators" -> ","]

points[data_, size_] := (#[[2]]) & /@ Select[data, #[[1]] == size &];

ViolinPlot[file_, style_] := 
  Block[{data, sizes}, 
    data := load[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], file}]];
    sizes := ((#[[1]]) & /@ Tally[(#[[1]]) & /@ data]);
    DistributionChart[points[data, #] & /@ sizes, 
                              ChartLabels -> sizes, ChartStyle -> style]];

PointPlot[file_, markers_, style_] := 
  With[{data = load[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], file}]]},
    ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> markers, PlotStyle -> style]];
```

Using [example data](http://pastebin.com/hqp15b1Z), the first plot has been generated by

```
ViolinPlot["data", {Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]]}]
```

I got the [averages](http://pastebin.com/wrUpU2i4) outside of Mathematica, so the second plot is done by

```
PointPlot["averages", {"[FilledCircle]", 6}, {Directive[Red]}]
```

The failed combination is a simple

```
Show[ViolinPlot["data",{Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]]}], 
     PointPlot["averages", {"[FilledCircle]", 6}, {Directive[Red]}]]
```

Comment: Your two plots have different `PlotRange`s, so combining them with `Show[]` is certainly not going to give tidy-looking results...

Comment: They have the same (from 0 to 1000000), even though the first plot does a bad job of showing that (thanks to overlapping labels). The question is (?) how to tell Mathematica that.

Comment: Not according to `AbsoluteOptions[graphic, PlotRange]` (or more compactly `PlotRange[graphic]`)...

Comment: @J.M. That's what I suspected: Mathematica does not give `DistributionChart` its proper range. If there is a way to tell it the plot range to use, that would constitute an answer.

Comment: @J.M. (as you are a mod, by proxy) I am not convinced this is a duplicate of the suggested question. I run 8.0.4.0 and the command given in the other question produces the desired result for me. The same hack may work, but I thought there should be a "nice" solution (but maybe there is not).

Comment: "I am not convinced this is a duplicate of the suggested question" - That's why I didn't vote to close. You might want to take the matter to meta, as two other mods feel otherwise.

Comment: @J.M. If I remember after the paper deadline, I may do so. We decided not to use these plots, anyway, but the issue is still interesting. Thanks!