# DistributionChart only shows entries with more than one value

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

**[DistributionChart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionChart.html) does not show entries for sublists containing only one element.**  Although I can understand why this would be reasonable (there's no "distribution" of a single element), it seems that at least some of the display options such as "PointDensity" should at least plot the points in question.

For example:

```
data = {{39.}, {82.}, {97., 99.}, {112., 109., 115.}, {124., 126., 123.,128., 120.}};

DistributionChart[
 data,
 ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity",
 ChartLabels -> Range[5]]
```

[image: example of a DistributionChart result]

shows the points associated with the sublists containing more than one element, but does not show any of the points in the first two sublists.

A hacky way to do get this to display is to add a duplicate entry to the single-member lists, e.g., redefining:

`data = {{39.,39.}, {82.,82.}, {97., 99.}, {112., 109., 115.}, {124., 126., 123.,128., 120.}};`

for the example above gives:

[image: slightly better output]

which at least shows something, although the presence of two points is undesirable.

**Is there a better idiomatic way to shows these single points on this type of plot?**

Using `Show`-ing with a  `ListPlot` ([as in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/combining-and-aligning-chart-type-graphics-with-regular-plots)) seems even more complicated.

I suspect there's a way to do it by defining a special [ChartElementFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html), but I don't understand graphics well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replicate singleton data (as you did)
2. Pass the original data as metadata and
3. Use the metadata (`#3[[1]]`) as the second argument of the function `"PointDensity"`; that is, use `ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementData["PointDensity"][#, #3[[1]]]&`.

```
DistributionChart[Thread[(data /. {a_?NumericQ} :> {a, a}) -> data],
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction ->
  (ChartElementData["PointDensity",  "PointStyle" -> 
       Directive[Black, PointSize[Medium]]][#, #3[[1]]] &), 
 ChartLabels -> Range[5]]
```

[image]

**Update:**  We can use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to place points less randomly than the built-in `"PointDensity"` does:

```
ClearAll[cEF]
cEF[cf_: "Quantile", opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {ChartElementData[cf, opts][##], 
    Darker@Darker@Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], 
    PointSize[Medium], 
    Point[Transpose[{Most @  Rest@Subdivide[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], 
          1 + Length[#3[[1]]]], #3[[1]]}]]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
DistributionChart[Thread[(data /. {a_?NumericQ} :> {a, a}) -> data], 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
 ChartLabels -> Range[5]]
```

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> cEF["SmoothDensity"]` to get

[image]